# Using promises hides outer scope from async callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

My code currently takes the form:

```
var x = 1;
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    request(url, function(err, res, body) {
        if (x == 1)
            resolve(body);
    });
});
```

Why is x undefined in that case?

If I instead leave out the promise (not desired), like so:

```
var x = 1; 
request(url, function(err, res, body)) {
    if (x == 1)
        // use body
});
```

I am then able to access x successfully. How can I keep the promise but still be able access x?

Comment: Your first example still has access to `x`, I suspect the issue is elsewhere. http://jsfiddle.net/tckq4r93/

Comment: you have a syntax error, the `)` at line 3 it should be at the end of line 6.

Comment: That is an excellent example! It reassures me to know that the promise container may not be the issue. If I find the solution and it is relevant, I will keep this question up, otherwise I will delete it to save myself from being downvoted anymore.

Comment: @Gesper, thanks for spotting that. I actually do have the ")" in my actual code. I just typed up this simple example too quickly.

Comment: it appears as though you may have *tried* to edit out your syntax error, but you only added the `)` on line 6, you still didn't remove the `)` on line 3.

Comment: @Claies, you guys are good! These small syntax errors aren't the problem though. It's a tricky async problem. Back to debugging ...

Comment: Please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). As it is now, the code you've posted doesn't reproduce the problem you're describing. This means it isn't possible for anyone to help you.

Comment: Do I post this short code snippet for the SSCCE here?

Comment: OK, this was not my problem. I am going to post a new question with a new code snippet that is more descriptive in hopes of someone being able to help.

Comment: @user1234 Yes. Usually when someone asks for changes you can just edit your question to add them. Then you can ping the user if you think they'd be willing to help using @<username>.

Comment: Ah, yeah, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31255858/passing-changing-value-to-asynchronous-function is a completely different problem.