# Passing changing value to asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

In the code below, I am adding a value to comb, trying to use that value in an asynchronous function, and then changing the value of comb. The value of comb within request is not as desired since comb.pop() occurs multiple times before request's callback fires. After searching many questions on stack overflow, I have tried putting a closure around request that took comb as input, but that did not work. How should I go about this?

```
comb = [1,2,3];
arr = [10,20,30];
promises = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    comb.push(arr[i]);

    var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        request(url, function(err, res, body) {
            // use comb
            if (/* comb meets certain condition */)
                resolve(body);
        });
    });
    promises.push(promise);

    comb.pop();
}
```

Here is my attempt at using a closure, which did not work:

```
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    (function(comb) {
        request(url, function(err, res, body) {
            // use comb
            if (/* comb meets certain condition */)
                resolve(body);
        });
    })(comb);
});
```

Comment: Show us the closure example. Yes, you need one, and it will work if done correctly.

Comment: So what are you trying to do? Work with a copy of comb as it  was when the Promise was instantiated?

Comment: That looks good, but will only work for basic types like number. Objects are always passed by reference so the above solution won't be enough to make a copy of an object. Something like `Array.prototype.slice.call(comb)` should be able to copy an array (shallow copy only).

Comment: @PSkocik You should edit your answer to demonstrate how the argument can be copied using `slice`.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for simple types:

```
  var promise = (function(combCopy){
     var ret = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          request(url, function(err, res, body) {
              //comb refers to the outside comb
              //combCopy refers to the copy
          });
      });
     return ret;
   })(comb);
```

Objects are always passed by references so passing an object as a parameter won't copy the object. You'll need to do that manually.

```
   var promise = (function(){ 
     //this creates a new scope -- something that might not be necessary
     var combCopy = Array.prototype.slice.call(comb); //shallow-only
     var ret = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          request(url, function(err, res, body) {
              //comb refers to the outside comb
              //combCopy refers to the copy
          });
      });
      return ret;
   })();
```

Comment: I think you forgot the `comb` parameter/argument for the IIFE. It might also be possible to just pass `Array.prototype.slice...` as the argument where you had `comb` at the end before and thus avoid the extra statement.